# Copy data between buckets - RIAK

Tags: riak

I have a bucket b1 containing log data. Now I am trying to copy them to a new bucket by adding a add secondary index.In the old bucket, each entry has JSON with 60 blocks. I would want each block to be written as a new entry in the new bucket.

I used riak java client, read each entry from old bucket , parsed the JSON and made 60 write calls [one for each block in the json] to the new bucket by adding secIndex. This worked fine. But the whole process is really slow and my old bucket has almost 10 million entries.

Is there a more efficient way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way that could possibly speed it up (but would also place a lot of load on the cluster) would be to develop one or two custom map and/or reduce phase functions and perform the split and inserts as part of one large mapreduce job. It would be possible to divide this up into several smaller tasks by e.g. using key filtering.

As you would need access to the internal Riak client in order to insert the new records, these functions (at least the insert function) would need to be developed in Erlang, as it is currently not possible to perform inserts from JavaScript.

This would take some time to develop and test, so if this is a one-off activity (which it sounds like) it might not be worth it.

You might be better off trying to partition the data and try to perform the migration in multiple parallel streams if you are not already doing this.

Comment: Thanks Christian. Yes you are absolutely right, this is a one-off activity. With the riak java client , it looks like the process will take weeks. When you said migration in multiple parallel stream, did you mean run multiple process which will stream portion of the keys from old bucket and  and move them to the new one?

Comment: If you have any secondary indexes on the records you could use this to split the data up in ranges. If not, you could have one thread retrieve the data and a pool process them. I assume the processing and inserts is the step that is taking longest.

Comment: It may also be worthwhile spreading the load across the cluster if you are not already doing this.

Comment: I am also assuming that you are using the pbcClient as it is faster than the HTTP client...

Comment: Thanks Christian. Sounds cool. Actually I was using the httpclient for writing data to the new bucket. Will try out the pbcClient with thread pool for writing. When you said load balancing did you mean this http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/tutorials/System-Planning/#Network-Configuration-/-Load-Balancing

Comment: With spreading the load I simply meant setting up connections to all nodes in the cluster and having them all handle requests.